Custom preference center with person accounts
I'm creating a custom preference center using a Marketing Cloud Cloud Page and I want it to be integrated with Salesfoce Sales Cloud.
I've done this before on standard accounts (contacts + accounts) and I normally update the field hasoptedoutofemail which sits on the contact object.
When I look in SalesCloud when its configured for person accounts, I see I have the field: hasoptedoutofemail on contact and personhasoptedofemail on account?
Which one do I update?
Thanks

The easiest way is to update hasoptedoutofemail attribute of the account object within Salesforce Sales Cloud along with contact object within the marketing cloud

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
